# Service runs on XP but not in Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-service

I have a service that uses a certain port and it is for TCP and runs fine in windows xp but starts and immediately stops in server 2003. when launched in server 2003 i get a dialog box that says

> The service started but stopped
>   because it had nothing to do.

This is for an instant messenger program o the service would need to be running all the time. What would allow a service to keep running in xp and stop it on server 2003. i have also added exceptions through the firewall for the program and the port even though the IM is local network only. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The service probably stops because of some unhandled exception. Is there a resource the service is trying to use, but can't access because of security limitations?

Some things that come to my mind are:

- denied access to a file and/or folder
- network resource
- the user running the service (System, Network Service Account ...) lacks some permissions
- missing configuration

If you're the author of the service, [try to catch the error and write it to the event log](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/756428-windows-service-starts-immediately-stops).

Comment: The only dependency it has is on the remote procedure call. The thing that gets me is there are three services total, one for an unused port and it uses UDP and two for two other unused ports and they both use TCP. The TCP ones do not start and stay running and the UDP one does. The user logging in is a super admin for the domain so it's likely not a permission issue. and i did not author them.